# How will fix Inaccessible issue for function app created in ILB ASE in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, app-service-environment

I am trying to create a function app in azure ILB ASE but failed to open Kudu due to its inaccessibility. How I configure it correctly?

[image]

Comment: I mean, if its hosted on an ASE it wouldn't be accessible from the "outside", right?

Comment: But from a VM which is in same virtual network can access, right?

Comment: yeah, it would be. I never tried this scenario and it would make sense if the portal had access to the webapps on the ASE, but I cant confirm or deny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Azure function is deployed in ILB ASE, it can **only be accessed from the virtual network**. If you want to access the function outside the VNet, you need to deploy a public Azure application gateway to expose the internal endpoint. The Azure application gateway will work as a reverse proxy to route the incoming traffic to the appropriate endpoint.

**References**:

[Integrate your ILB App Service Environment with the Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/integrate-with-application-gateway)

[Private Function Apps in Azure Government using App Service Environment (ASE)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/03/15/private-function-apps-in-azure-government-using-app-service-environment-ase/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this issue - [Document how to use Functions in an ILB ASE](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/377) and this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e2aa429-727c-467d-b28e-9fa15e189835/azure-functions-runtime-is-unreachable-when-deployed-on-a-isolated-asp-ilb-ase), make sure you meet the requirements.

1. Be in the same vnet as your ILB ASE
2. Have a valid cert for the default domain and the default scm domain. `*.yourILBDomain.com` and `*.scm.yourILBDomain.com`
3. In addition to having a certificate, you also must configure the DNS for the ILB domain.